# random.Next(); C# How to make it so it chooses more than one number inbetween given values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
    public MostDamagers(int amount, bool isRandomized, int howManyGetsPicked, params ILootDef[] loots)
    {
        Random chosen = new Random();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.loots = loots;
        int min = 1;
        int max = amount;
        int isChosen = chosen.Next(min, max);
    }
```

Using this code (its not done, just assigning the ints and all that atm), I want to make it so instead of
`int isChosen = chosen.Next(min, max);`
it choosing one number between "min" and "max" ints, it chooses whatever
`int howManyGetsPicked` 
is set to.

So if I set 
`int howManyGetsPicked`
to 5, I would want 5 random values between "min" and "max" to be picked.

(If that is possible, thanks either way, because I know by default it only grabs one random number between the two values)

Comment: dont initialize your Random object over and over when that is called or your next Q will be 'why are the numbers all the same?'  Otehrwise call it in a loop

Comment: I know, I am just setting the ints and vars for now, will add the necessary code when needed.

Comment: or replace that with: `picks = Enumerable.Range(1, howManyGetsPicked).Select( q =>  RNG.Next(min, max + 1)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < howManyGetsPicked; i++)
{
    chosen.next(min.max); //You need to save this in a list or array.
}
```